# folium.Marker does not does decode properly

Tags: python, folium

I have a folium map called imap.
I have created a string object called test_mark which is a string 'Coruña-Torre de Hércules: Presión: 964.4hPa'

```
test_mark = 'Coruña-Torre de Hércules: Presión: 964.4hPa'
folium.Marker(location=(43.30,-8.30),popup= test_mark, icon= folium.Icon()).add_to(imap)
```

When I check the marker on the map, what I get is 'CoruÃ±a-Torre de HÃ©rcules: PresiÃ³n: 964.4hPa'.
I guess it might be some kind of encoding problem, but I can not figure out how to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `charset=windows-1252` through `meta` tag for Spanish language such as

```
import folium

lt = 43.30
ln = -8.30

imap = folium.Map(location=[lt,ln],zoom_start=19)

test_mark  = '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></head>'
test_mark += '<strong>Coruña-Torre de Hércules: Presión: 964.4hPa<strong>'

imap.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(test_mark))

folium.Marker(location=[lt,ln],
              popup= test_mark,
              icon= folium.Icon()).add_to(imap)

imap.save('map.html')
```

Comment: Thank you so much Barbaros. It works perfectly fine as html but it still does not work on the Jupyter Notebook. I guess it has something to do with the notebook itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just encode the text as `ascii` with errors `xmlcharrefreplace`, in python you can do this: `str(x.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'))[2:-1]`